# Are these diodes on or off?

Tags: diodes

[image]

Is my understanding correct? Since the voltage past the first Diode is 10. That would mean that the diode will be reverse bias while the second diode will be forward bias? If this is true, that means that the Volage V is simply -15V since the first diode is off.

Diodes are ideal.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115537/discussion-on-question-by-king-of-zimbabwe-are-these-diodes-on-or-off).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another bad water analogy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRwHqS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. "I told you this was bad."*

- Water is being fed from a +15 m head through a pipe with some resistance to flow.
- There are two outlets - one at +10 m and one at -15 m.

To what level do you think the tank will fill?

Comment: The -15m outlet.

Comment: Right. The tank represents your node marked 'V'. What is the voltage at V?

Comment: This is my favorite answer ever.  The label for Figure 1 made me LOL.

Answer (score 1):

> ... the first diode will be reverse bias while the second diode will be forward bias... Diodes are ideal.

Then the explanation is extremely simple:

- The first diode is *off* and you can think of it of as "nothing" (open circuit).
- The second diode is *on* and you can think of it of as a "piece of wire" (short circuit).

So, your circuit can be thought of as a resistor "stretched" between two sources with opposite voltage polarities (+15 V and -15 V). Note that actually, they are connected in series with total voltage of 30 V across the resistor.

However, the resistor does not play any role here because the output voltage V is completely determined by the source -15 V. Why?

Figuratively speaking, two voltage sources with opposite polarities are connected to the same point V... and "struggle" to impose their voltages on it. Only, the positive source does it through a resistor while the negative source does it directly... and wins the "fight".

Or, you can imagine that two voltage sources - *real* (+15 V) and *ideal* (-15 V), are connected in parallel. What would be the voltage across them? Of course, -15 V (the voltage of the ideal voltage source).

> Since after the resistor the voltage will want to go to the lowest voltage source (-10V).

Exactly... the voltage will "go" to the negative terminal of the lowest voltage source. For the purposes of understanding, such a personification of soulless electrical elements and quantities is very useful. It shows that you have imagination... and this is a very valuable gift...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to note that the IV characteristics of the combined diodes is the same as the IV characteristic of \$D2\$. Hence \$v=-15V\$, so \$D2\$ is on and \$D1\$ is off.

Note that the IV characteristic of two components in parallel is given by
\$(v,i_1+i_2)\$ where \$(v,i_k)\$ is characteristic of the individual components.